# Abstract Algebra elementary question

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\pi^3)$. How can we find a basis for $F(\pi)$ over $F$ ?

Comment: let me know if another hint is needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as a good hint I'd say that $\,\pi\,$ is a root of $\,f(x):=x^3-\pi^3\in\Bbb Q(\pi^3)[x]=:\Bbb F[x]\,$ , and from here $\,[\Bbb F(\pi):\Bbb F]\leq 3\,$...